# MapMarker infoWindow disappearing after 3 seconds, when switching between the other app - swift

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios, infowindow, background-foreground

When I switch between multiple apps or bringing the current app from background, Map marker info window is disappearing after 2-3 seconds. Also, marker resetting into default size from magnified mode.
Currently using Swift 4.

[MapMarker infoWindow disappearing after 3 seconds, when switching between the other app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6sA9.gif)